# javascript array - .each() loop - detect string and swap

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, each

I am trying to work with an array and am having some difficulties. I know this is elementary but I am still new the jquery/javascript so not sure why this isn't working

```
var vids = new Array();

vids[0] = $('#tab_content_1 iframe').attr('src');
vids[1] = $('#tab_content_2 iframe').attr('src');
vids[2] = $('#tab_content_3 iframe').attr('src');
vids[3] = $('#tab_content_4 iframe').attr('src');   

//alert(vids);

$.each(vids, function() {
    if( $(this).attr('src').search('?w=opaque')){
            $(this).attr('src').replace('$?=opaque', '?w=transparent');
            alert('hi');
        }
});
```

I am attempting to search the url of an iframe for the opaque parameter and swap it out with the transparent parameter.

Comment: What part doesn't work?  Do you see your alert?

Answer (score 3):

You have several issues, but the biggest is that you're creating an array of the iframe *src* values, but then trying to reference the parent frames.  Here's what you need (note the many simplifications):

```
$('#tab_content_1 iframe, #tab_content_2 iframe, #tab_content_3 iframe, #tab_content_4 iframe', function() {
    var frame = $(this),
        src = frame.attr('src');
    if (src.indexOf('?w=opaque') != -1)
    {
        frame.attr('src', src.split('?w=opaque').join('?w=transparent'));
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```

Note that the `search` method was being misused, and that `replace` doesn't work the way you're using it.  Thus, the updated code uses `indexOf` to check the string and `split/join` to replace.

Also, we're using a jQuery DOM query selector directly at the start instead of a separate iframe array (which is redundant).

Finally, note the use of [`attr(prop, value)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the attribute.

Comment: There was a typo (`src.split('?=opaque')` vs `src.split('?w=opaque')`).  That might be the issue; otherwise, start adding `console.log(...)` calls to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this would work:

```
$.each(vids, function () {
   if ($(this).attr('src').indexOf('?') > 0) {
      var str = $(this).attr('src').substr(0, $(this).attr('src').indexOf('?'));
      $(this).attr('src', str+'?w=transparent');
      alert($(this).attr('src'));
   }
});
```